# How to enable Vue devtools in production mode for chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vue-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension, and using a vue-cli webpack config. I'd like to be able to use the vue devtools after running the *npm run build* command.

I tried to add `Vue.config.devtools = true;` in main.js, or change `NODE_ENV: '"production"'` to `NODE_ENV: '"development"'`, but vue devtools is still not showing up.

What can I do to enable vue devtools in production mode?

Comment: is Vue.config.devtools = true at the top of the file? also check for AdBlock i had some problems with it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First,use Vue devtools in Chrome ext Development environment is enabled.

## Experience

These days I'm developing a Chrome browser plugin.I found that `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` undefined.

Although not a big problem, but I want to solve it.I have searched a lot of information online.

#### example:

1.open `chrome-extension://<hash>/app.html`

2.set `Vue.config.devtools` to be true

3.grant Vue Devtools ext file access

**but all doesn't work.**

## Solution

As we know, `vue-devtools` is an essential piece of the Vue ecosystem, but it is currently tied to a web browser.

But now There is a package provides a standalone vue-devtools application, that can be used to debug any Vue app regardless of the environment. Now you can debug your app opened in mobile browser, safari, native script etc. not just desktop chrome or firefox.

This package name is `vue-remote-devtools`, which is a standalone electron shell to remotely debug Vue apps!

Let's have a try:

Following the `README.md` steps,

1. Install the package globally:

   `npm install -g @vue/devtools`
2. run in your terminal: `vue-devtools`

   you will see a electron app appear like this
   [image: Electron Shell]

3.inject the script tag to your Chrome Extension `.html` file.

## Warning

Due to Chrome's Content Security Policy (CSP) restrictions on plug-ins,Chrome Extension's web request may be blocked.

At this point you need to modify the Chrome Ext configuration file `manifest.js`.

```
content_security_policy: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8098; object-src 'self'"
```

Although you can copy `content_security_policy` to the corresponding file `manifest.js`, but I still hope you can find out what the CSP is:

[What is Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

## Finally

Connect Success！
[image]

Ref:

[vue-remote-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/master/shells/electron/README.md)

[DevTools for Chrome Extension Development.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/120)

Comment: After doing all this it still didn't work for me, it would disconnect immediately after connecting. Only after downgrading to vue-devtools@^5.1.4 did it finally work.

Comment: How can I modify `manifest.js` file?

Comment: @AhmedMamdouh Any questions here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have the problem because I'm trying to use vue devtools in Chrome extension. Unfortunately, it's impossible to use vue devtools because extension pages are served over `chrome-extension://`.

Further reading: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/120